# define method in model that can be accessed in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined a problems method in my Report model.  I need to use the value of Report.problem in the report's controller while defining the action show. But i keep getting the error message 'undefined method problem'. How do i solve this? Any assistance would be greatful.

I have a report model and a problem model that contains a list of all problems.

In report model

```
def problems1
Problem.find(:all, :conditions => )
end
```

In the reports controller i need something like

```
def show
  @report = Report.problems1
end
```

Comment: Can you add some code of what is failing?  Both model code for the method you are trying to call and controller code that generates the error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you have to assign `self.method_name` to use as a class method

Follow following rule for Model methods

Class Method

```
def self.problem

end
```

in controller

```
Report.problem
```

Instance method

```
def problem

end
```

in controller

```
report =  Report.new
report.problem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define method as class method

```
class Report < ActiveRecord :: Base
 def Report.problem
  puts 1
 end
end

Report.problem
>1
```

But if you define method as object

```
class Report < ActiveRecord :: Base
 def problem
  puts 1
 end
end
```

This method call

```
report = Report.new
report.problem
>1
```